# Why can't I connect to LAN game in Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm running Minecraft Bedrock on Android and am trying to join a game running on an XBox One on the LAN.

When I click on "Play" and then the "Friends" tab I see the other person under "LAN Games" and it says "1/8" with a green circle.  But when I click on it, I get the message:

```
Wow this server is popular! Check back later to see if space opens up.
```

When I click on Ok, it says something about generating world, but then goes back to the previous screen where I first tried to join at.

There is plenty of space!  Why can't I connect?

Comment: This seems like a strange issue. Could you add some screenshots (or even better a screen recording) of your process of joining the LAN game?

Answer (score 1):

Check the port in server.properties. I set mine to 25565 for some external testing and noticed that I got this message afterwards. I changed it back to 19132 and haven't had an issue since.

Answer (score 0):

check server.properties file and increase the number of maximum players (something like 20)

maybe for some error the server opens up different temporary connections which saturate the maximum amount of players